# How to animate element height in React with ReactCSSTransitionGroup?

Tags: reactjs, actualheight, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to animate element height with `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`,
so this is what I would want the animation looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/cherrry/hgk4Lme9/

The problem is that I don't always know the element height,
so I tried to hack the `scrollHeight`, `clientHeight` or something similar during `componentDidMount` and try to set `node.style.height` or add rules to stylesheet

http://jsfiddle.net/cherrry/dz8uod7u/

Leaving animation looks good, however when element enters, it flash a bit and the scaling animation looks strange

It should be because of asking `node.scrollHeight` caused the rendering occur immediately, so is there anyway to get the same information and inject css rules before animation start? Or should I think other way round?

I'm not very satisfied with the `max-height` solution, as the resulting animation speed will be very strange when `max-height` is not close to or smaller to `height`, and my components' height do vary a lot.

I could imagine the final solution could be a bit messy,
but I think making it into a Mixin will be nice enough to reuse it anywhere

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had a same problem and ended up writing a standalone component for animating height.

You can see the demo here:
https://stanko.github.io/react-animate-height/

It is much easier to use, and whole library is really small (~200 lines)

```
<AnimateHeight
  duration={ 500 }
  height={ 'auto' }
>
  <h1>Your content goes here</h1>
  <p>Put as many React or HTML components here.</p>
</AnimateHeight>
```

Sorry for the shameless self promotion, but I think it can save you a lot of time if you have more than one component to animate.

Cheers!

Comment: Uh, this is **not** shameless self promotion as you have explained it as well. Good one. But be careful answering oooooold questions.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it was an old question, my bad!

Comment: I love react animate height but how can I get the same effect on the width.

Comment: This doesn't work when using react-style programming, i.e. `<AnimateHeight> { this.state.show ? <div class="div-to-show"></div> : null } </AnimateHeight>`

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Use this:
`<AnimateHeight height={ this.state.show ? 'auto' : 0 }><div class="div-to-show"></div></AnimateHeight>`
AnimateHeight takes care of accessibility and hides the content.

Comment: The devs of the react `CSSTransition` component should be ashamed since they were not able to provide me an as easy API as yours. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16):

After a bit more experiment, I've come up with a solution by using the low-level API `ReactTransitionGroup` instead of high-level `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`

Here's the JSFiddle with a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cherrry/0wgp34cr/

Before the animation, it's doing 3 things:

1. get computed height, paddings and margins
2. hide the element with `display: none` and add `.anim-enter` to set height to 0
3. create css rule for `.anim-enter-active`

To start the animation, it's doing 2 things:

1. unhide the element
2. add `.anim-enter-active` to start the animation

Some numbers and class name in JSFiddle were hard-coded, but it should be easy enough to transform the "mixin" into a React class as a replacement of `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`

Answer (score 2):

A very easy and nice approach is by handling scaleY instead of height.
The hover should set the attribute transform: scaleY(1)  (originally => transform: scaleY(0) to hide it) and the animation should target transform attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to import a module or use qjuery, here is a template using React ref (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Basically you get the height it will be, grow to that height, switch back to auto.  On the way back switch to the height it is, then back to 0.

```js
class CollapsibleSectionBlock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showContent: false,
            height: "0px",
            myRef: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
        if (prevState.height === "auto" && this.state.height !== "auto") {
            setTimeout(() => this.setState({ height: "0px" }), 1);
        }
    }

    setInnerRef = (ref) => this.setState({ myRef: ref });

    toggleOpenClose = () => this.setState({
        showContent: !this.state.showContent,
        height: this.state.myRef.scrollHeight,
    });

    updateAfterTransition = () => {
        if (this.state.showContent) {
            this.setState({ height: "auto" });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { title, children } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 onClick={() => this.toggleOpenClose()}>
                    {title}
                </h2>
                <div
                    ref={this.setInnerRef}
                    onTransitionEnd={() => this.updateAfterTransition()}
                    style={{
                        height: this.state.height,
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        transition: "height 250ms linear 0s",
                    }}
                >
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have the parent container hidden / with display: none => this will not work: this.state.myRef.scrollHeight ( it will be equal to 0 )

Comment: Correct, an object does not have a height when its not rendered.