# Animate list height when deleting items

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, react-transition-group

I am using React Transition Group to animate in/out some list items, example: https://codesandbox.io/s/43v5wj62q9?file=/styles.css

However I need to smoothly animate the list height whenever a list item is added/deleted, right now it just snaps to its intrinsic height without a smooth transition.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337045/how-to-animate-element-height-in-react-with-reactcsstransitiongroup) might be helpfull